# Save custom meta box data more organized way in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, meta-boxes

I have added a meta box on the `new-post` page which allows users to add photos and write some description. See the attached image.

[image]

So, now I want to save this data. As you can see, A photo itself has its own meta data too (Title, URL and Description) So, storing these values in a multidimensional array will make more sense I guess.

```
$photo_meta_data = array(
             'photo1' => array('title'=>'aaa', 'url'=>'http://..', 'desc'=>'ffff'),
             'photo2' => array('title'=>'aaa', 'url'=>'http://..', 'desc'=>'ffff'),
             'photo3' => array('title'=>'aaa', 'url'=>'http://..', 'desc'=>'ffff'),

        )
```

But, how to do this ? This is the code I'm stucked in my metabox.

```
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'photo-title1' ] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'photo-title1', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'photo-title1' ] ) );
   }
```

I'm just saving field data just like a single value.

And currently I'm storing values in the `wp_postmeta` table like this...

```
PostId   MetaKey       Value
 175   photo-title1    .....
 175   photo-URL1      .....
 175   photo-desc1     ..... 

 175   photo-title2    .....
 175   photo-URL2      .....
 175   photo-desc2     ..... 

 176   photo-title1    .....
 176   photo-URL1      .....
 176   photo-desc1     .....
```

So, this is lot of data for the `wp_postmeta` table isn't it ?

Is there a more organized way of doing this ? Should I use a separate table for these custom meta data ? Or just do like I've done ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save all the meta in one multi dimensional array like this:

```
// Save the meta value as one multi dimensional array, like below
$photo_data = array(
   array(
       'title' => 'Name here',
       'url' => 'http://example.com',
       'description' => 'My description here...'
   ),
   array(
       'title' => 'New name here',
       'url' => 'http://example.com',
       'description' => 'New description here...'
   )
);

// Save it using either update_post_meta() or add_post_meta()
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'photo_data', $photo_data );

// Reference it or get it like below later on:
$photo_data = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'photo_data', true );

// Get the values like below...
echo $photo_data[0]['name'];
echo $photo_data[0]['url'];
echo $photo_data[0]['description'];
```

Remember to loop through your data before saving the post meta to the WP database, use appropriate sanitation functions in WP.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Comment: I did this.. But, this saved an string called "Array" in the DB for photo_data key.. Is that normal ?

Comment: Are you using some kind of sanitation function or filter to modify the post meta value? Like: sanitize_text_field() when using: update_post_meta()? It should work out of the box to save post meta values as arrays.

Comment: You should not sanitize the whole array, loop through each value and add an custom sanitation for each value. Try removing the sanitation function and see if its saved correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do :) Anyway, before you answered, I just used php serilize() function. So, it worked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Store an array in 1 metakey for the post like so:

```
[
    "photo1" => [
        "title" => ...
        "URL" => ...
        "data" => ...
    ],
    "photo2" => [
        "title" => ...
        "URL" => ...
        "data" => ...
    ],
]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really get what you're suggesting... Could you please be little bit clear.. ? I'm little bit new here..